# Trying to dual boot Windows 8.1 with Ubuntu on Acer Aspire 779G

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8, uefi, acer

As it says in the title, I am trying to dual boot 8.1 with Ubuntu 14.04 Lts.  I am starting my first big boy job as a software analyst and as you can guess they primarily use linux platforms.

I have researched how to dual boot 8.1. and ubuntu, and I am stuck at the point where i need to disable secure boot. 
I have tried accessing the UEFI setting from restarting from Windows, but it does not show up.  I have tried selecting F2 at start up, create a supervisor password, but the secure boot setting does not show.

I think the problem is my laptop is not natively 8.1, it is originally a 7 and then back in Fall 2013 i upgraded to 8.0 then 8.1.

Any advice is surely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you do not need to disable "**Secure Boot**" to install **Ubuntu** any more. It looks like your computer is with bios, not **UEFI**, becuase it was natively with **Windows 7**.

You do not need to do anything special to install in dual boot with Windows 8. Just do not forget to shut down Windows properly. It is hibernated by default.

So just install Ubuntu normal way, like with **Windows 7**. Good luck!

Comment: Ok, so I changed the boot order, placing the USB devices up the top and the hard drive near the bottom, that didn't work.  I also tried using F12 and del.  That didn't work.  I did an advance restart and that didn't show the buttons to select the boot up the device.  Any other ideas?

Comment: What does "did not work" mean?

Comment: "did not work" means, it booted from my harddrive and detected nothing from my USB.  I set the ubuntu image on my usb using universal usb from pendrivelinux.com

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with Windows. You just can't boot from a usb drive. In some bioses you need to select HDD as boot device and then in another option select your USB drive as HDD. It is a matter of bios, or your flash drive.

Comment: Most computers from 2013 do use UEFI, but most also have a CSM to support BIOS-mode booting, so it's really guesswork as to which is used. The partition table should be diagnostic: If it's GPT, the computer uses EFI; if it's MBR, the computer is booting in BIOS mode. Note that some methods of writing `.iso` files to USB drives drop one or the other (BIOS or EFI) support, which could explain Ubuntu installer boot problems.